# android - AlertDialog.Builder error - "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(HelloPlugin) is undefined"

Tags: android, cordova, alert

I'm trying to display an alert box in android but the "this" in new AlertDialog.Builder(this) gives the error, "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(HelloPlugin) is undefined". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Java:

```
public class HelloPlugin extends Plugin implements iRcpEvent2,
    OnCompletionListener, IOnHandlerMessage {

public static final String KEY_ENCODING = "my_encoding";
public static final String KEY_SAVELOG = "my_saveLog";
public static final String NATIVE_ACTION_STRING = "nativeAction";
public static final String SUCCESS_PARAMETER = "success";


public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray dataArray,
        String callbackId) {

    if (NATIVE_ACTION_STRING.equals(action)) {

        String resultType = null;
        try {
            resultType = dataArray.getString(0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("HelloPlugin", ex.toString());
        }

        if (resultType.equals(SUCCESS_PARAMETER)) {

            RcpApi2 rcpAPI = RcpApi2.getInstance();
            rcpAPI.setOnRcpEventListener(this);

            try {
                boolean t = rcpAPI.open();

                if (t = true) {
                    try {

                        boolean k = rcpAPI.startReadTagsWithRssi(maxTags,
                                maxTime, repeatCycle);

                        if (k = true) {

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            builder.setTitle("Message")
                                .setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();

                            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, k);

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,
                            "Reader Not Opened :(");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,
                    "Oops, Error :(");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: post the whole class where you used it

Comment: edited to show whole class, thanks.

Comment: `Cordova`. You should have tagged your questions appropriately.

Comment: also post the class where `HelloPlugin` is used.

Comment: HelloPlugin is being used by javascript. I'm using javascript to communicate with a java jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wonders about this, here is the answer:

To get the context of a Cordova plugin, you can use the following piece of code:

```
((Activity)ctx)
```

For example, if you want to make an alert builder, do this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(((Activity)ctx));
builder1.setMessage("Test Alert");
AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
alert11.show();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

the Constractor must get Context

[AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

try using `getApplicationContext()`

or pass `Context` to this Class